# C#'s ListBox doesn't see my overrided Sort() method

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, listbox

I'm trying to override Sort() method in my custom control. When my control contains ListBox and then I override Sort() method, everything works.

But when I want my ListBox **(1)** to be extended by another ListBox **(2)**, that contains Sort() method, and then add that ListBox **(1)** to my UserControl, then it sorts too, but isn't using my Sort() method (seems like it doesn't see my Sort(), just normal Sort() from ListBox class).

My ListBox **(2)** contains code:

```
//...
public class MyListBox: ListBox
{
    public MyListBox
    {    
        this.Sorted = true;
    }
    // more methods
    override protected void Sort() 
    {
        // sorting code
    }
}
//...
```

And my custom control looks like:

```
//...
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // method in MyControl.Designer.cs (myListBox1 is declared in that class)
    }
    // more methods
    public ListBox.ObjectCollection Item //that's because I want my control to behavior like ListBox instead of creating void AddItem(Object) method, etc...
    {
        get { return myListBox1.Items; }
    }
}
```

so I think everything should work, but it doesn't... Any ideas?

Comment: isn't sort an extension method? Not sure you can override it...

Comment: Did **override protected void Sort()** compiled? it should be **protected override void Sort()**.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger, I can override it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx                                @Wagas Raja, I think it doesn't matter, but I tried both ways. PS. when I wrote **"When my control contains ListBox and then I override Sort() method, everything works."** I ment **"when my form contains overrided ListBox with Sort method everything works, but in user control it doesn't"**

Comment: can you show how you call the Sort method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your Sort, it could be necessary to cast your ListBox to your custom ListBox type (if it is in the base type) to use your specified Sort method.

```
((MyListBox)myList).Sort();
```

---

you must use your overriden ListBox with its correct type, I mean use it as MyListBox and not as ListBox. Don't be afraid that you need to implement all the other methods, you're overriding an existing class and not an interface. you can use all the needed base methods.

Comment: I don't want to call it. It's not visible outside MyListBox class. It should be called automaticly every time I add new item to ListBox, that's why I set this.Sorted to true. It is sorting, but not using my overrided method, so that's strange for me... It could be ok, but I want to Sort different then starndard ListBox' Sort().

Comment: And I know it's really not calling this method, because when I put there MessageBox, it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Even if BlackCamel did want to call it directly like that it won't work because Sort is protected and MyControl does not inherit from MyListBox.

Comment: There must have been my mistake somewhere in code, I couldn't find it and not using that class anymore, but accepting that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly `myListBox1` is of type `ListBox` not of type `MyListBox` which is why your Sort isn't being called.

Comment: no, itis of type MyListBox. I wrote: when I put MyListBox on Windows Form it sorts my way. But when I use MyListBox exactly the same way in User Control it doesn't work. I know it seems strange, because everything look like I made mistake somewhere, but I was thinking about it many hours, trying everything, analysing code hundred times... And also I didn't show you all my code, because it's hundreds of lines, but believe me I use MyListBox, because it's round ListBox with PictureBoxes around it, so if I used normal ListBox, I would have known about it.

Comment: your explanations are a bit confusing and your code snippets are too tiny to really understand the problem.

Comment: ok, maybe someone tries to create control like this when he/she has nothing else to do, I think he/she would have the same problem. Or someone who had the same problem will answer my question. Maybe  I just should override public void Refresh() method and call there my Sort() method and forget about it.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood, what is `Listbox (1)` in your question?

Comment: drs9222, sorry I wrote too quickly... ListBox (2) is MyListBox extending normal ListBox (1). So MyListBox == ListBox (2) containing overrided method Sort().