# Overridden winform ListBox.Sort() not getting called as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listbox

I'm trying to override the sort method in a listbox to sort in descending order.

Code:

```
public CustomSortListBox()
    : base()
{
}

protected override void Sort()
{
    if (this.Items.Count > 1)
    {
        bool swapped;
        do
        {
            int counter = this.Items.Count - 1;
            swapped = false;

            while (counter > 0)
            {
                // set this to != to reverse sorting
                if (this.Items[counter].ToString().CompareTo(this.Items[counter - 1].ToString()) != -1)
                {
                    object temp = Items[counter];
                    this.Items[counter] = this.Items[counter - 1];
                    this.Items[counter - 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }

                counter -= 1;
            }
        }
        while (swapped);
    }
}
```

Now, I would intuitively expect that this method would get called whenever items are added to the list, and this seems to be how it works with the base ListBox when ListBox.Sorted = true.  However, with my CustomSortListBox after adding items to the list, my custom sort was not being respected, and furthermore, the overridden method was not getting called, not even hitting breakpoints, when the item list is changed.

Then I read this https://gfaraj.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/custom-sorting-for-listbox-in-c/ and it says "Don’t forget that Sort is only called when the Sorted property goes from false to true"  This seems rediculous to me, but sure enough, when toggling Sorted off and back on, my custom sort gets called and works.

Interestingly, after this, leaving Sorted = true, new items added are sorted using the base Sort() method, creating a mixture of ascending and descending items.  Until you toggle Sorted false -> true again.

I would even settle with the hacky solution of putting Sorted = false; Sorted = true; in an event handler for ItemsChanged, but such an event doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this Sort override be respected when the list is added to?

(I have seen [C#'s ListBox doesn't see my overrided Sort() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161117/cs-listbox-doesnt-see-my-overrided-sort-method) but his issue isn't clear, seems to have just "gone away" and the answer he randomly selected is not ideal, or even compilable due to inaccessible protection level)

Comment: It's not necessary to copy-paste code from MSDN article. You can just point that you want some custom `Sort` method to be called each time when you add items

Comment: Totally agree with @SergeyBerezovskiy! I was going to say the same in regards to this "Copy-Paste" question (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Plus, what exactly the question poster is asking? Some clarity would be helpful. Best regards,

Comment: Looking at the ListBox source one can see that the Add Method doesn't call Sort it just calls an (internal) BinarySearch method to get the index where to put the new item. So overriding sort won't help. But why do you want the ListBox to sort. For me a ListBox ist something to show data not to sort data. If you want something sorted put your data into a list, sort that list and bind that list to the ListBox.

Comment: This behavior is well-documented.  There is a good reason it works that way, the native ListBox control keeps its own copy of the strings that are displayed in the list.  So in order to sort them, that list has to be first emptied, then the sorted items re-added in their sorted order.   That's very expensive, too costly to do so every single time an item gets added.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy This is actually not the same code that is on MSDN.  But I get your point that it wasn't really needed in the post.

Comment: @Ralf I was just trying to keep it "simple" or I would have used ObjectListView, but yes data binding seems like a better solution.  Out of curiosity though, if the Sort method isn't what is called when items are added, when is it called?  Why does it exist?  There are many articles on SO and elsewhere on the internet that point to overriding this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you understand that to have your `Sort()` method called, the `ListBox.Sorted` property needs to transition to `true`. This is documented, though poorly. This is the only time, as far as I know, that the `Sort()` method is called, and this understanding is consistent with the documentation.

> Interestingly, after this, leaving Sorted = true, new items added are sorted using the base Sort() method, creating a mixture of ascending and descending items. Until you toggle Sorted false -> true again.

When you add items to the `ListBox`, the order is handled not by the `Sort()` method, but by the control's collection object. This object does a binary search to find the correct place to insert the new item. Unfortunately, it is hard-coded to use a string comparison on the list box item text for this.

This is why adding items causes them to be ordered according to the default implementation. But it's not using *"the base `Sort()` method"* to do it.

For the Winforms `ListBox` class, if you want efficiently sorted items, your best bet is probably to not override `Sort()` nor to use the `Sorted` property. Instead, provide a helper method to add new items and have that method do the appropriate binary search on the `Items` collection to find the insertion location.

You would have to implement a helper method anyway to get notification of items being added, and it will be more efficient to do sorted insertions than to re-sort the entire collection on every insertion.

You could (as suggested in the comments) bind a sorted collection to the `ListBox`, but that's going to be more work, especially since AFAIK there aren't any built-in collection types that support binding and which are inherently sorted.